# Error while using user defined service in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have created an angularjs service which I am trying to access in a controller by injecting the service in the controller. Here's the code that I have used:

```
  angular.module('ControllerModule').controller('AwarenessCntrl',['TestService',
    function(TestService, $scope, $state)
    {
        console.log(TestService.list()[0].label);
        $scope.goToHome = function() 
        {
          $state.go('home');
        };

    }]);
```

I get the following error message in the console:
Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating

```
'$scope.goToHome = function() 
    {
        $state.go('home');
    }')
```

Here's the code that I have used for the service:

```
angular.module('AppServices').service('TestService', [TestService]);
function TestService() {
var items = [{
    id: 1,
    label: 'Balle Balle, Service Chal Payi'
}, {
    id: 2,
    label: 'Item 1'
}];
this.list = function() {
    return items;
};
this.add = function(item) {
    items.push(item);
};
}
```

The console is able to print the data from the service; but it also gives an error message that I have mentioned above. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `$scope, $state` in the string array list too.
See the [Angular Docs on Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

Best practice here would be to include build in angular features first and then custom services afterwards.

```
angular.module('ControllerModule').controller('AwarenessCntrl',['$scope', '$state', 'TestService',
    function($scope, $state, TestService)
    {
        console.log(TestService.list()[0].label);
        $scope.goToHome = function() 
        {
          $state.go('home');
        };

    }]);
```

Comment: Thanks Oliver. This fixed the problem that I was facing.

Comment: Awesome :), if you wouldn't mind marking it at the answer then as it will help those in future.